# Switch between gestures on a view with same touch

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

In `UICollectionView` I added  `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. At first `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is disabled, I want to enable it when `contentOffset.y` of `UICollectionView` reaches some value during scrolling. I am trying to achieve this by following code. But it works only in second touch on the screen. I want to work with gesture when contentOffset.y is 44 without taking off the finger.

```
 func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if collectionView.contentOffset.y == CGFloat(44) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. According to your logic it happens only on second touch. Try to enable or disable pan gesture in scrollView Delegate method like below.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     if collectionView.contentOffset.y < CGFloat(44) {
        panGesture.enabled = false
    }
    panGesture.enabled = true
}
```

Comment: thanx man for the answer. But i need to take off the finger and again touch to work on that logic.

Answer (score 0):

In your gesture's began state check the condition

```
 func gestureTap(sender : UIGestureRecognizer){        
   if sender.state == .began {
       if collectionView.contentOffset.y == CGFloat(44) {

       } else {
         return
       }
    }
}
```

Or

In scrollView Delegate method you can check too. Check below

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     if collectionView.contentOffset.y < CGFloat(44) {
        yourGesture.enabled = false
    } else {
    yourGesture.enabled = true
   }
}
```

Comment: thanx man for the answer. To use first answer gesture should be enabled and if it is enabled then scrolling cannot be done. The main thing is during scrolling we should put the finger off and touch again to work on that logic.Actually i need to work with gesture only when contentOffset.y is 44.

Comment: @sant05 Updated answer